# How to delete oldest week(period) in MS SQL database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, sql-server-2008r2-express

MS SQL 2008R2 Express, I have database - one table with rows. And when db size became about 10gb I need to clean one  oldest week in this table (I dont know the date). Could you help me with script? Thanks.

UPD1.
There is column DateAndTime, so i make query like this in VBA:

```
strSQL = "SELECT DateAndTime
                ,TagName
                ,Val
                ,SetPoint
                ,Limit_H
                ,Limit_L
                ,Result 
          FROM dbo.Statistic 
          WHERE DateAndTime  BETWEEN CAST('" & TimeBegin & "' AS datetime) AND CAST( '" & TimeEnd & " ' AS datetime) 
          Order By DateAndTime desc , (CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(TagName)=1 THEN CAST(CAST(TagName AS float) AS INT)END ) desc"
```

Comment: How do you identify "oldest week"? Do you mean this is the first data loaded and you don't have any timestamp in your table? Deleting only by metadata?

Comment: is there any identity column? or is it ordered in any way?

Comment: can you post sample data, pls?

Comment: "i dont know the date", of what? You do not have a timestamp column in your table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this -

```
DELETE YOUR_TABLE
WHERE DATE_COL BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(DATE) FROM YOUR_TABLE) AND (SELECT MIN(DATE) FROM YOUR_TABLE) + 7
```

Comment: `delete from` is correct syntax, and you need `dateadd()` for SQL server

Comment: I think `DELETE` solely will also takes care for the same. And this syntax should work though i have not tried it yet.

Comment: @JohnHC It works on my MSSQL db:  SELECT GETDATE()-7

Answer (score 1):

As Ankit suggested, use the min() of the date and add a week

```
delete 
from dbo.statistic
where dateandtime between min(dateandtime) 
                    and dateadd(week, 1, min(dateandtime))
```